# Subtype constraints with generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Having this code:

```js
export interface IModel {
  id: string;
}

export interface StatusResponse<
  TModel extends IModel = IModel,
  TResponse = any
> {
  item: TModel;
  response: TResponse;
}

export class Transport<TItem extends IModel = IModel> {
  save(item: TItem): StatusResponse<TItem> {

    const result: StatusResponse<TItem> = {
      item: { // << error
        id: ""
      },
      response: {
        stat: "ok"
      }
    };

    return result;
  }
}
```

Inside the `save` function I'm getting this error:

```
 Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TItem'.
  '{ id: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TItem', but 'TItem' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IModel'.
```

What is confusing to me is that the interface `StatusResponse` has the same constraints and defaults for generic `TModel` as class `Transport` for `TItem` however, inside the `save` function they are represented as a mismatch.

If I code the `save` method like this, there are no problems.

```js
  save(item: TItem): StatusResponse {

    const result: StatusResponse = {
      item: {
        id: ""
      },
      response: {
        stat: "ok"
      }
    };

    return result;
  }
```

Please note I removed the generic type from `StatusResponse` so it picks up its defaults.

I'm not sure what's going on here.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkIATYAGzgG8BYAKDkRIC44BnGKZAcwG56AvvXqhIsRCjRZccAMoxMMAK5sASsDaQkbYAB56jACrEylUKiQk2BExTgBeG6QoAaA3EPrNEbXkeYkAE96AD5qdwRUAFtWY2dyfgY4KA0tHVivNOBEoToRcGh4bHJMNmtDKADvWF1DfGi4c2BLayJ4hydTMNo8pIB6PvZMADdgAApI4BiPeqmASlZ5RRVMnx1qOCQIRqgoaHc2EfHJ6brohbkFZTVUtb0zqe7hJMYB7DX4FLYlchhFq5Wt18HSocAGm22aD2UHcjHe2k+Gh+f0uyxu3l8tVmUTCjh6jAJiGirFB4N0uh20NhhKYrAARHTqYwBG4XgSvlkSUyCRxFPSIABrRls5nUgSJakpZRQJDJJG-RKiugCIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think what will happen if one will use the above class with generic parameter requiring additional properties. For example:

```
new Transport<{ id: string, additionalProp: string }>()
```

Save method will produce result with missing `additionalProp` - that's why you're getting the error.

---

Not sure if that makes sense in your case, but you could spread the original item into response to preserve type structure:

```
export class Transport<TItem extends IModel = IModel> {
  save(item: TItem): StatusResponse<TItem> {

    const result: StatusResponse<TItem> = {
      item: {
        ...item,
        id: ""
      },
      response: {
        stat: "ok"
      }
    };

    return result;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQFkIATYAGzgG8BYAKDkRIC44BnGKZAcwG56AvvXqhIsRCjRZccAMoxMMAK5sASsDaQkbYAB56jACrEylUKiQk2BExTgBeG6QoAaA3EPrNEbXkeYkAE96AD5qdwRUAFtWY2dyfgY4KA0tHVivNOBEoToRcGh4bHJMNmtDKADvWF1DfGi4c2BLayJ4hydTMNoktkwAN2AACkjgGI96sYBKVnlFFUyfHVrJqO7hJMZsJfgUtiVyGFmFZTVUpb066LDHHsZ7xGjWO4f7gDoP0ai3TdeEFjgACJAe4HgIfq9kudfM9Qa8OIpWICIABrEG-Ri5MGJOEpZRQJBQ-aHRKYwRAA)